# Google IMA SDK Flash ads cannot be resized when fullscreen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, sdk

I am using latest Google IMA SDK for video ads, in that 
the flash ads are showing properly when loaded but its not displayed
when userclicks fullscreen,
i tried to capture the stage resize and tried to change the width and
height using

```
flashAdsManager.adSlotHeight(main.stage.stageHeight)
flashAdsManager.adSlotWidth(main.stage.stageWidth)
```

but i am getting following error

```
1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method adSlotHeight through 
a reference with static type com.google.ads.instream.api:FlashAdsManager.
1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method adSlotWidth through 
a reference with static type com.google.ads.instream.api:FlashAdsManager.
```

can u please help how to resize flash ad when fullscreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those  functions are setters

```
function set adSlotWidth(value:Number):void;
```

so you need to do

```
flashAdsManager.adSlotHeight = main.stage.stageHeight;
```